# How to get NSDate day, month and year in integer format?

Tags: iphone, datetime, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to get the day, month and year components of `NSDate` in integer form i.e. if the date is 1/2/1988 then I should get 1, 2 and 1988 separately as an integer. How can I do this in iOS? I found the similar question but the method `descriptionWithCalendarFormat`: gives a warning and seems to be deprecated by now.

Comment: See [Convert NSDate to an Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059292/convert-nsdate-to-an-integer) if only a single integer is needed for `NSDate`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Swift

```
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: self)
let day = components.day
let month = components.month
let year = components.year
```

For convenience you can put this in an `NSDate` extension and make it return a tuple:

```
extension NSDate: Comparable {

    var dayMonthYear: (Int, Int, Int) {
        let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: self)
        return (components.day, components.month, components.year)
    }
}
```

Now you have to write only:

```
let (day, month, year) = date.dayMonthYear
```

If you wanted to e.g. get only the the year you can write:

```
let (_, _, year) = date.dayMonthYear
```

Comment: I like your approach. A suggestion though is to change the parameter naming to `(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int)`, that way you can use the result by using `date.dayMonthYear.day`, `date.dayMonthYear.month`, `date.dayMonthYear.year`.

Answer (score 224):

Here you are,

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:currentDate]; // Get necessary date components

 [components month]; //gives you month
 [components day]; //gives you day
 [components year]; // gives you year
```

You can use NSDateComponents for that as above.

Please visit [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Comment: +1 for providing the code for the correct answer.  But you should mention that the info comes from NSDateComponents, not NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @Black Apologize for that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @ Janak Nirmal  Write be specific point you could not explain how to get string format for day, month,year, an User could not understand.

Comment: @annu What do you mean ? You mean you can not understand the answer given ?

Comment: @JanakNirmal you should explain it how get exact value.

Comment: To avoid deprecation warnings: NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate: currentDate];

Answer (score 17):

Yes by the use of NSCalendar, though, i think this will make your work.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [components day];    
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use NSDateComponents to get this,

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dComp = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                      fromDate:currDate];

int day = [dComp day];
int month = [dComp month];
int year = [dComp year];
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Put it in an extension and live your life

```
extension Date{
    var day:Int {return Calendar.current.component(.day, from:self)}
    var month:Int {return Calendar.current.component(.month, from:self)}
    var year:Int {return Calendar.current.component(.year, from:self)}
}
Date().day//22
Date().month//4
Date().year//2017
```

Swift 3.0 (It's an iteration of previous answers, but solves it for all your future app projects)

Answer (score 7):

To those who just copy and paste directly from the web, like me, this is a small update for iOS 8

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components day]; //Day
[components month];//Month
[components year];//Year
```

The difference is `NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay` `NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` have been deprecated

Answer (score 2):

U can try this .......

```
Mycal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
today = [NSDate date];
compA =[Mycal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];     
FirstDateofMonth=[today dateByAddingTimeInterval:([compA day]-1)*(-24*60*60)];

compA =[Mycal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:FirstDateofMonth];
today = FirstDateofMonth;
compA = [Mycal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
[compA setMonth:([compA month])];
[self DrawMonthInPortraitView];
[compA retain];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate]; // Get necessary date components

[components month]; //gives you month
[components day]; //gives you day
[components year]; // gives you year

NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Months:%d Day:%d Year:%d",[components month],  [components day],[components year]];
NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
print("hours = \(year):\(month):\(day)")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.