# how to find out what day is a date in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to find out a what day is a day in ios by objective-c,is that anyone done this before,or any pod can help to address?

now i got an NSString @"2015-07-01" and i want to get what day is it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214094/how-to-get-nsdate-day-month-and-year-in-integer-format. might be help you

Comment: Do you want the 01 or Wednesday?

Comment: i want the Wednesday